# Issues executing VBA code using a button and also getting an output as '0

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and very keen in understanding it better. I have written below code using `countifs`

Issue 1 - When I debug, I do not get any error, instead I get output as `0` even though my input file looks as below.
However, if I copy-paste the keyword 'Walkthrough' in the code and execute it, I would get the correct output i.e. `2`

Issue 2 - If I assign a button to this macro and run, I would get an output as `0`

**Input File**

```
Column A      Column B
Walkthrough   Not Started    
Walkthrough   Not Started
```

**Actual Code**

```
Sub countif_test()
    Dim type_of_test As Long
    Dim Walk As Worksheet
    Dim source As Worksheet

    Set source = Worksheets("Archer Search Report")
    Set Walk = Worksheets("SOX_Dashboard_Walkthrough_Stat")

    type_of_test = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A2:A3"), "Interim", Range("B2:B3"), "Not Started")

    Walk.Range("C2") = type_of_test
End Sub
```

Request you to assist in regard this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> When I debug, I do not get any error

Because your code is correct

> instead I get output as 0 even though my input file looks as below.
>   However, if I copy-paste the keyword 'Walkthrough' in the code and
>   execute it, I would get the correct output i.e. 2

The `CountIFs` function that you have written, actually checks for 'Interim' in cells A2:A3, and 'Not Started' in B2:B3.
Since the first condition is not met, you get count as `0`

However using 'Walkthrough' in the code in place of 'Interim' would be
`Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A2:A3"), "Interim", Range("B2:B3"), "Not Started")`

Which will search for 'Walkthrough' in cells A2:A3 which is found in both rows, also the 2nd condition is met.
So you get Output as `2`

> If I assign a button to this macro and run, I would get an output as 0

Because that's your code